# Counterexample for open sets in Nested Set Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm referring to this theorem:

Let $\{F_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a descending countable collection of nonempty closed sets of real numbers for which $F_1$ is bounded. Then 
$$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n \ne \emptyset.$$

I'm wondering why the sets must be closed. Is there a simple counterexample of sets, at least one of which is open, for which the intersection gives us $\emptyset$?

I'm also wondering the same thing about boundedness, but haven't thought about it as much.

p.s. descending sets means $F_1 \subseteq F_2 \subseteq F_3 \subseteq \cdots$.

Comment: Well, simply take $F_n = (0, 1/n)$

Comment: possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228520/question-regarding-nested-interval-theorem

Comment: Your "P.S." should go the other way: descending means $... \subseteq F_3\subseteq F_2 \subseteq F_1$. (Or use $\supseteq$.)

Comment: "...at least one of which is open*..."   Just a comment:  asked often here and usually asking about "open" instead of closed.  The correct question is "Is this true if I drop "bounded?"  "Is this true if I drop "closed?"  Since the negative of closed is not open, it always strikes me as odd that the question is so frequently posed this way.   Also Mr Fequish should think too about whether the possibility that *a finite number* of the $F_n$ fail to be closed   would change the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Take $I_n=(0,1/n)$ the intersection is empty

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, $F_n = (0, 1/n)$ provides a counterexample: $\bigcap_n F_n = \emptyset$.

Boundedness is also essential: if $C_n = [n,+\infty]$, then $\bigcap_n C_n = \emptyset$.